# Is there some library available for IQR-Codes (not QR-Codes)?

Tags: javascript, android, api, open-source, qr-code

Recently I found this: http://2d-code.co.uk/iqr-qr-code/

This is a QRCode but an improved version. I use some QRCode libraries in some projects and it is a great technology but IQR-Code sound very promising. Less the size (sometimes size is a problem) and can contain more characters on a very small footprint.

To get into the new technology, see also [this page](http://www.qrcode.com/en/codes/iqr.html).

I want to try and play with these new QRCode to find out if it is really useful and suitable to fit into one of my projects but I cannot find any library for it. I want to find a library that can be used in Android, Delphi, PHP, AS3 or/and javascript. Is there a 'hidden' link on the internet that brings me to such library?

The next thing I wonder about is reading speed. For example, the ZBAR and XZing library reads QR-Codes at razor speed. And what about error correction, is it accurate enough? Because it is using a smaller footprint, is it easy to read by a camera? Is it worth it to invest time in this new format?

Does have anyone more information about this or is there a demo project that I can download?

### **EDIT 12/01/2018:**

[image: YAB]

---

Today I found YAB (Yet Another Barcode), initiated by fraunhofer institute. It is a 3D barcode with colors that can hold more data in a smaller form factor. It is free to use, source code available and deserves more attention, take a look at:

- https://github.com/jabcode/jabcode

Or use the online demo:

- https://jabcode.org/

Comment: +1 for the question, since I didn't know about them.

Comment: Ok so now my question: Can I freely manipulate, create wrappers, transcribe to other languages, make apps etc with JAB code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a 'hidden' link on the internet that brings me to such library?

After researching and googling, it seems that, unlike QR codes, the use of iQR codes is not free licensed by Denso Wave, the owner of the patent.

> Is it worth it to invest time in this new format?

The format isn't really that new (it's been around since at least 2011) so, in my opinion, the lack of global success and the fact that it isn't freely distributed answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have read that the technology is free to use, no issues. It doesn't matter or is required for the project that it is widely adopted standard. In some cases it better to use a technology that is not widely adapted.

Comment: OK, but are you sure it's free? I read Denso Wave decided not to exercise their patent rights on QR codes, so they made them free to everyone, but I couldn't find anything regarding iQR codes. The lack of software for iQR codes after these years makes me think it isn't free, although they also plan to make the specification available and in the public domain for use by anyone free of charge, subject to Trademark.

Comment: I believe all kind of issues with the format is not about patent but about trademark, as far I can find information about this. The weird thing is that QR-CODE has the same issues and is widely used. I think that most of people don't know the existence of IQR-CODE. Another reason that I can think of is that QR-CODE does the job very well, so why change something that is good or... maybe there are some read issues with this new format? I dunno.

Comment: UPDATE: Just send a question about this to DENSO, the owner of the barcode.

Comment: UPDATE: Still got NO ANSWER on e-mail to DENSO.

Comment: I don't really think there are any read issues with this format. Probably, it's just a case in which the industry prefers an already established standard. In spite of this fact, I really think it's a very interesting format, as there are many cases in which a thinner code is better than the standard QR code.

Comment: "QR-CODE has the same issues (patent and trademark) and is widely used". That 's because DENSO decided to "give it away free", but as I said before, I really think that's not the case for IQR-CODES

Comment: Any response from DENSO? In the german wikipedia it reads (regarding the iQR Code)[google translate]: "The manufacturer Denso Wave plans the disclosure of the specification and the free use by everyone in the public domain in respect of the trade mark as is already done for the QR code. In addition, the registration as an ISO standard is sought." No source is cited tho.

Comment: No, no response at all from Denso.

Comment: Take a look at my edit of the question.

Comment: Ok so now my question: Can I freely manipulate, create wrappers, transcribe to other languages, make apps etc with JAB code?